# Play framework 2.2.1 get all items from conf/messages file

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I want to list all data from conf/messages file in play framework version 2.2.1

For example, if my message file contains this:

```
item.name = NAME
item.age = AGE
item.town = TOWN
```

I know what `Messages.get("item.name")` does, but is there a way to get a list of all values (the right part of `item.name = NAME`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages are kept inside a Map[language, Map[key, text]] inside of `MessagesApi` which is what is returned from the api method on `play.api.i18n.MessagesPlugin`, so you should be able to access it from there and manually look through all values.

Something like:

```
val allLanguages = play.api.Play.current.plugin[MessagesPlugin].get.api.messages
val allValues =
  for {
    (_, oneLangage) <- allLanguages
    values <- oneLangage.values
  } yield values
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I make it by reading the file using java FileReader :)